# Evaluating the value of the multipliers of L1 and L2 type

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have a very simple question. When we performs gradient descent with regularization terms of the $L_1$ and/or $L_2$ types, namely expanding the loss function $L$ with

$$
L_r=L+l_1 \sum_i| \pi_i |+l_2 \sum_j ||\pi_j||^2
$$

Why we do not include $l_1$ and $l_2$ variables in the update rule of the gradient descent?

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand your question, but if you want add regularization term to your cost function you will see it in gradient descent update rule. And you will see it with l1 or l2 parameter, this parameter will sets trade off between needed classification accuracy on test set and norm of weights.
For example this parameter called lambda here http://dudarev.com/wiki/ml-class-logistic-regression.html

Comment: The question is, why we don optimize the l1 and l2 terms inside the gradient decent? I guess that doing this will return always values of l1 and l2=0, but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hyperparameter, you cannot update weights and this parameter simultaneously. If you will optimize it with weights simultaneously, with respect to loss function on training and (or) testing set - yes, this parameter will become 0 and it will zero out penalty part. Because when you train complex model - it can easily overfit your dataset, and predict values perfectly, in this case best thing that optimization process can do to minimize loss, when model labels dataset perfectly - zero out this parameter. So parameter which was designed to prevent overfitting will do nothing useful.

But you can do [grid search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization#Grid_search)